# Search dynamic filter expression through grep

Tags: jquery, grep

I have an array

var num=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

and my filterexpression is dynamic,i.e it keeps changing with conditions:

```
var filterExpression="num!=2"

If(//some condition)
{
filterExpression=filterExpression+ "num!=5"
}
```

I want to search this using grep:

```
$.grep((num), function (num) {
                    return filterExpression;
                });
```

this is not working, any roundabout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

```
num={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

is not Array but Object.

the problem is that you are using double quote to set your filterExpression.
once you use double quote, it will be String and never be executed.
If you use `eval`, you can execute String as Javascript Code though,It's not recommended except the case you can't avoid using because of security and performance issues.and in this case, You don't have to use it.

```
var numbers =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];


var filterExpression = [1];

if("someCondition"){
  filterExpression.push(4);
}

$.grep((numbers),function(number){
  for(var i in filterExpression){
    if(number == i){
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
});
```

Eventhough I do not recommend, Code below is the way using String as filter expression.

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

var filterExpression = "number!=2";

if("some condition"){
  filterExpression += "&& number!=5";
}
$.grep((numbers), function(number){
  return eval(filterExpression);
});
```

Comment: Case for using string expression fails, as eval already evaluates the result and then pass  to the grep's function.

Comment: You might be misunderstanding how it works.what is required is to return true or false depending on the filterExpression. and it is doing so.the function returns [1,3,4,6,7] which is deleted 2 and 5 according to the filterExpression(any value except 2 and 5)

Comment: this works fine for numbers ,but  in my actual scenario I have a list , and i need to filter the list on the basis of multiple properties,
   var filterExpression = "AcceptedFlag== 1";
if("some condition")
{
filterExpression=filterExpression+"&& isDeleted==0";
}
eval dosen't work in this case

Comment: it seems fine.double check your variable names are correct and condition is what you expected.

Comment: Works fine,the error was while assigning value to filterExpression I shuld have written array.PropertyName,
e.g:  var filterExpression = "array.AcceptedFlag== 1".Thanks..